# Finding a literal within a database definition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

A database contains in its definition some hardcoded literal, which should be replaced by a generic function call.

The literal may appear in procedures, triggers, defaults, checks, etc. - basically "everywhere".

I'm using this code to find the literal:

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%HARDCODEDLITERAL%'
```

I just would like to know if this code is sufficient to find all occurrences, or if I might be overseeing some occurrences within the database ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%HARDCODEDLITERAL%'
```

Comment: Sorry, no. This returns even LESS than my statement. For example, your statement does NOT return any `DEFAULT`  definitions.

Comment: @SQLPolice:- What do you mean by `DEFAULT definitions.`? Is it the system defintions you are referring at?

Comment: I mean the `CREATE DEFAULT` statement.